# Charles proxy malformed request url error

Tags: http, web-scraping, request, charles-proxy

I'm trying to setup Charles in order to intercept requests from my iphone's browser. I tried setting up the proxy with the default settings but end up getting this error.

```
    Charles Error Report
Failure
Malformed request URL "/". Consider enabling Transparent proxying.

The actual exception reported was:

com.xk72.proxy.ProxyException: Malformed request URL "/". Consider enabling Transparent proxying.
```

How to fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Under the proxy menu select Proxy Settings. In there is an option to enable Transparent proxying.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This today not working